# How to serialize two related models in Django

Tags: python, django, database, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have two model:

```html
class Liver_Function_Tests(models.Model):
    blood_lab=models.ForeignKey(Blood_Lab,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, related_name='liver_function_tests')

class Blood_Lab(models.Model):
    patient=models.ForeignKey(Patient,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
```

I have created serializer for `Liver_Function_Tests` model

```html
class Liver_Function_Tests_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Liver_Function_Tests
        fields = '__all__'
```

Now, I need to include this serializer into `Blood_Lab_Serializer`

```html
class Blood_Lab_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    liver_function_tests_details = Liver_Function_Tests_Serializer(source='liver_function_tests.last', required=False)
    class Meta:
        model=Blood_Lab
        fields = ['id','patient', 'liver_function_tests_details']
```

The problem is, when creating Blood_Lab I have to assign the blood_lab forign_key that is not created yet, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/bloodlap/`
[image]

What is possible solutions to this problem ?

Comment: Take a look at this https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/